# Making "default saved" work with GRUB2...?

Tags: linux, grub

I just installed Moblin Operating System. It's using GRUB2. On my Ubuntu 8.04 GRUB 0.97 was being used in which i was using the **default saved** option comfortably. I found that with GRUB2 i should not edit /boot/grub/menu.lst directly *but I did* :) because my Moblin does not contain any **/etc/default/grub** where they say I should do the modification I want.

So what I did is as following which did not work:

```
default=saved
timeout=1
#splashimage=(hd0,0)/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz
#hiddenmenu
#silent
title Moblin (2.6.31.5-10.1.moblin2-netbook)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31.5-10.1.moblin2-netbook ro root=/dev/sda1 vga=current
        savedefault=1

title Pathetic Windows
        rootnoverify (hd0,1)
        chainloader +1
        savedefault=0
```

By doing so I should have automatically switch between Moblin and Window at each boot but it's not working.

Almost all the troubleshooters on internet are saying that I should enable the **DEFAULT=save** option in **/etc/default/grub** but I am unable to find this file. Any idea what else should I do?

Thanks a lot

**Update:**

I used the equal to sign because by default my menu.lst had an entry as **default=0**. However, **default 0**, is also working fine.

Moreover the **menu.lst**, i have is actually a symbolic link to **./grub.conf**. I have also noticed that **grub-intall** and **grub-set-default** commands are not working.

Comment: You're using 0-based numbering for disk partitions -- that doesn't look like GRUB2, that looks like Legacy GRUB.

Comment: if you have a working */boot/grub/menu.lst* you are *not* using Grub2.  Grub2 uses */boot/grub/grub.cfg*.  you may see both configuration files if you've updated to Grub2 from an older installation that used Grub1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct syntax for enabling `savedefault` in `/etc/default/grub` (GRUB 2) is with the lines:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

and *not* with the line `DEFAULT=save` that the enquirer suggested.

After adding the two lines above to `/etc/default/grub`, one has to update GRUB's configuration, as a superuser, with the following commands:

```
grub-mkconfig
update-grub
```

At least on Lubuntu 12.10, `grub-mkconfig` is not needed (as it, without options, dumps the config file to stdout). The only needed command is `update-grub` which actually invokes `grub-mkconfig` with the proper `-o file` option.

Comment: One detail is that at least on Ubuntu, the memtest entries won't be saved incase you decide to try them to test the feature quickly...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if GRUB allows the `=` sign; my configuration reads `default saved`.

Your problem is that the `Pathetic Windows` entry does not do a `savedefault`, so the default entry is never changed to Windows.

**Edit**: Furthermore, `savedefault` by default saves the current entry; only if you give it a number will it save another entry than the current one.

Try this:

```
default saved
timeout 1
#splashimage (hd0,0)/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz
#hiddenmenu
#silent
title Moblin (2.6.31.5-10.1.moblin2-netbook)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31.5-10.1.moblin2-netbook ro root=/dev/sda1 vga=current
        savedefault

title Pathetic Windows
        rootnoverify (hd0,1)
        chainloader +1
        savedefault
```

I don't know Moblin but in other distributions it is common to have the configuration file somewhere in `/boot/grub`, not in `/etc`.

Comment: I would put the savedefault command first, as it is unclear to me wether chainloader or kernel calls exit the boot loader immediately..

Comment: I use the equal to sign because by default my menu.lst had an entry as default=0. However, default 0, is also working fine. Moreover the menu.lst i have is actually a symbolic link to ./grub.conf

I have also checked that grub-intall and grub-set-default commands are not working.

Comment: See also my edit. You shouldn't give `savedefault` a number.

Comment: the syntax is `savedefault N` not `savedefault=N` (again, if you want it to save another entry as the default -- if you want current entry, leave `N` off).

Comment: +1 cuz it worked for me (though the OP did ask about grub2)